# How to get my custom calculator to display on wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I built a custom calculator using HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery. 
I have a basic hosting account and loaded all the files through cPanel to my root directory. The  files include calc.html with a CSS folder holding my stylesheet and a JS folder holding my custom jQuery.

Now someone would like to put my calculator on their Wordpress site and we can not figure out how to do it. For now I just used iframe to show my site on their  Wordpress page but we want the calculator to be hosted from his site.
I tried copying and pasting my HTML code from my calc.html file into a Wordpress page which works but I do not have the styling of my CSS and the JS dose not function. So I used FileZilla and created a folder called CALC with the follwing path (public_html/wp-content/themes/parallaxpro/cyberchimpscss/calc/) and added the JS sand  CSS contents in there.

I linked my CSS in the header of my calc.html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public_html/wp-content/themes/parallaxpro/cyberchimpscss/calc/css/mainCalc.css">
```

I linked my JS towards the end of the body in calc.html

```
<script src="public_html/wp-content/themes/parallaxpro/cyberchimpscss/calc/js/main.js"></script>
```

I view the page and still have my ugly HTML code with no styling and no JS functionality.

Im new to Wordpress/coding and this is the first thing that popped in my mind so I tried it and failed.

I also thought I could put calc.html, mainCalc.css, and main.js inside of the calc directory i created(public_html/wp-content/themes/parallaxpro/cyberchimpscss/**calc**/)
and then use iframe to display calc.html on the wordpress page. I also failed at this.

I used

```
<iframe src="public_html/wp-content/themes/parallaxpro/cyberchimpscss/calc/calc.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: You probably want to built a pluginn for it: [(see here)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: If you want to put your calculator anywhere in wordpress site then see [how to make plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/) but if you want to use it in only one page then follow [how to create template in wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do with creating a custom page template.

Basically you will follow the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/ and create a page with the HTML + CSS + JS in the content part.

When you done, you just create a new page in the admin part, select the template from the list under the publish button. Save it, and that's it.
Its simpler from writing a plugin.

Comment: Awesome. I will take a crack at this later tonight! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Great. If it will actually help you, accept my answer.

Comment: No problem. Will be back on later with some results.